# SQLite Last Records in Order Added

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to push the last records from a SQLite table out to a chart. Let's say the data looks like this...

```
ID     Date_Time             Value
1      2014-10-21 10:00:00   60
2      2014-10-21 10:00:00   63
3      2014-10-21 10:00:00   65
.
.
.
450    2014-10-21 10:00:00   64
451    2014-10-21 10:00:00   61
452    2014-10-21 10:00:00   59
453    2014-10-21 10:00:00   58
454    2014-10-21 10:00:00   59
455    2014-10-21 10:00:00   61
```

Let's say I want the last 5 records to go to the chart, my query looks like this...

```
SELECT Date_Time, Value FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This gets the right data, but in the wrong order.  The DESC clause puts them in Id order 455, 454, 453, 452, and 451.  I want them in 451, 452, 453, 454, and 455.

There has to be an easy way to do this that doesn't require me to put in my own array than then re-sort.  However, it escapes me!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Change `DESC` to `ASC` to sort in ascending order.

Comment: @RyanWillis - That then gives me records 1 - 5, I need records 451 - 455, or did I miss something?

Comment: For only 5 records you could also use php's `array_reverse()` of course...

Comment: @RyanWillis - Got it - thank you! That helped tremendously.